# advective tem in conservative equation in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: partial-derivative, cylindrical-coordinates, finite-volume-method

A conservative equation for the general property $\phi$ can be written as:

$$
\frac{D \rho \phi}{Dt}=\nabla\cdot(\Gamma_\phi \nabla\phi)+S_\phi
$$

where $\frac{D}{Dt}$ is the material derivative, $\Gamma_\phi$ is the diffusion coefficient and $S_\phi$ is the source term of variable $\phi$. $\nabla$ is the del operator, used to calculate the gradient of a scalar field and the divergence of a vectorial field. The conservative equation as defined above is usually written in cartesian coordinates, so it is useful to use the $\nabla$ operator to write in a compact form the conservative equation for the property $\phi$.

My question revolves around the material derivate. For cartesian coordinates, it can be written as:

$$
\frac{D \rho \phi}{Dt}=\frac{\partial \rho \phi}{\partial t}+\vec{u}\cdot\nabla{\rho \phi}
$$

So the general conservative equation for the property $\phi$ is written in a more convenient way for finite volume analysis as

$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}+\nabla(\rho \vec{u} \phi) = \nabla\cdot(\Gamma_\phi \nabla\phi)+S_\phi
$$

Is this general conservative equation only valid for cartesian coordinates? The material derivative in cylindrical coordinates is not written as $\frac{\partial \rho \phi}{\partial t}+\vec{u}\cdot\nabla{\rho \phi}$, as is shown [here](http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.com.br/2008/08/derivation-of-navier-stokes-equations_17.html).

Answer (score 1):

The conservation equation is true in any coordinate system in its intrinsic form, i.e. where $\nabla f$ denotes the gradient of $f$ and $\nabla\cdot f$ denotes the divergence of $f$. However, the expression of the gradient and of the divergence operators with respect to the coordinates vary from one coordinate system to an other (see e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1445288)).