# Partial Derivative of Tan(y/x)

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, cylindrical-coordinates

Given that =tan/ by Cylindrical Coordinates, I have that [image]
... But how do you go from that to [image: din]?

In particular, why does the sec just disappear? Please assist. Thank you.

Reference Post: [Del operator in Cylindrical coordinates (problem in partial differentiation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445288/del-operator-in-cylindrical-coordinates-problem-in-partial-differentiation)

Comment: Please clarify: $\phi=\tan(y/x)$ or $\phi=\arctan(y/x)$?  The former is not how we define cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: The second image is the derivative of $\arctan( \tfrac yx)$ instead of $\tan( \tfrac yx)$.

Comment: @Azif00 Now I'm confused! I guess I mean arctan(y/x) then